# Jquery appendTo Duplicating content multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Every time I use JQuery's AppendTo(), it duplicates the items that I want appended. And every time I load in the page with AJAX (which includes the script) it duplicates it even more times! It only works normal for the first time after the entire page is reloaded.

```
$("<tr><td><input name='quantity[]'/></td><td><input type='text' name='ItemDescription[]'/></td><td><span class='remove'>X</span></td></tr>")
    .appendTo('.tbody');
```

Please note that I've also tried `append()`,

and

```
$('.tbody').html($('.tbody').html() + 'string');
```

and the same issue persists.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Can you describe what you're trying to do. From the look of your first code example, you're trying to add a new row to a table, and I can't see any issues with that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think op wants to append the element only once with the target element. The code that he uses would allow duplicating the elements since `$('.tbody')` would contain the previously appended one also. Am i right?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. And it works, the issue is that, it adds multiple rows to the table when the script fires. But I only want one row.

Comment: yes @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Comment: @user2993497 Then you can try out my answer below.

Comment: the script looks fine to me, unless it's being called multiple times or you have more than one element with class `tbody` (which results the same)

Comment: looks like you have duplicate event handler.. can you show how is your event handler registered and where

Comment: @ArunPJohny looks like you were right. It was fired by a simple click event. So i put an alert inside of it, just to confirm that it was only firing once. Turned out, it was doing it multiple times for some reason

Comment: now you have to just make sure that it does not happen.... if there are no other way use the syntax `$('some-selector').off('click.duplicate').on('click.duplicate', function(){})`

Comment: @ArunPJohny solved it. Answer so i can chose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it looks like you are running the script which is registering the event handler multiple times. The best solution is not to do that, ie try to run the script only once.

If you are doing to handle dynamic elements look at event delegation.

If that is not possible, another solution is to remove any handler before adding a new handler so that any given time there will be only one handler. Also you can use event namespace to make sure that you won't remove some other handlers

```
$('some-selector').off('click.duplicate').on('click.duplicate', function(){})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a copy initially before doing the appending process,

```
var copy = $('.tbody').html(); //This should be done initially before making any calls
$('.tbody').html(copy + 'string');
```

So that you wont append your elements repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks but technically i already tried this. At the bottom of my post, I said i did the same thing you did, except you stored the tbody's html in a variable i just plugged it straight into the function. I tried both ways, same result.

Comment: @user2993497 You are not getting it properly. I just asked you to maintain a copy from the beginning stage itself. `var copy` should be treated like a constant and it should be assigned with the relevant html string in the page load itself.

Comment: yes, i tried this, but it had the same result. The real issue was that the event that triggered the function was being fired more than once.

Answer (score 0):

When you use append(), it will be appended to the existing body (btw I dont know why you append a row to a body. This should be appended to a table). So if you call append() the second time, you will have two rows. Thats exactly what append() does. If you want to redesign the table after each load you have to clear all existing rows with

```
$('.tbody').html("");
```

But better use a table in the body and append the row to the table and clear the table.